# Conditionally include json field inside return statement

Tags: javascript, json

So, I came across an issue, I'm usually returning empty strings if I can't find a value or if it is undefined. Like so:

```
return {
  _method: 'update',
  link: get(media, 'link', ''),
  caption: get(media, 'caption', '')
};
```

where `get()` is a lodash function that simply returns something (in this case empty string) if it can't find value within a provided path.

however I now need to return nothing if the field is not there, I tried

```
return {
  _method: 'update',
  get(media, 'link', '') ? link: media.link : '',
  get(media, 'caption', '') ? link: media.caption : '',
};
```

but that is not a valid syntax.

Comment: did you meant `link: get(media, 'link', '') ? media.link : '',` ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar noup

Comment: @Ilja ^ above comment answers you.

Comment: @llamerr no no, in that case the link field would be there and I want to get rid of it if associated value is empty or undefined or null etc..

Comment: @Ilja Why not put `undefined`?

Comment: I think you will have to move that definition to _after_ your creation of the object, so you will have to do `var a = {}; var b = get(...); if(b) a[key] = b; return a;`

Comment: @PraveenKumar just due to how our backend guys handle it. They prefer it not to be there at all.

Comment: @Ilja Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I tested your idea of using undefined and it worked. I will up vote if you post it.

Comment: @Roberto Done long back. The `undefined` solution is not suitable here because the particular entry itself should not be there as per the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot have that field, then don't do object creation on the fly. Use something like:

```
obj = {};
// add static values here.
obj["_method"] = 'update';

// dynamic now
if (get(media, 'link', ''))
  obj["link"] = media.link;
if (get(media, 'caption', ''))
  obj["caption"] = media.caption;

// And finally return the obj.
return obj;
```

That's the best way I could think of.

Comment: Awesome, the only thing I changed is usage of dot notation i.e. `obj._method`

Comment: @Roberto The problem is, if you create `{rob: undefined}`, there will be an entry of `obj.rob`, which is not expected. Do you get it now?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you.